# Add formatted output from subprocess.check_output to list

Tags: python, subprocess, string-formatting

I am running `subprocess.check_output()`,and I'm trying to add the output to list. The sub-process returns as expected, however, it returns in a somewhat undesired format.
The output is given within brackets, which I'm trying to remove.

```
data = subprocess.check_output(path, args)
datastring = str(data)
print(datastring) #1
datastring = datastring.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
print(datastring) #2
```

Prints the expected output the first time at #1 with format

> [[Val1],[Val2],[Val3]]

After calling replace, it does not print anything at all.

I also want to append these values to a preexisting list.
This is my current attempt:

```
data = subprocess.check_output(path, args)
datastring = str(data)
print(datastring) #1
datastring = datastring.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
print(datastring) #2

list = [Name, ID]

string_list = datastring.split(",")
for i in string_list:
        list.append(i)
```

Any help on string formatting would be appreciated! Also, please suggest how appending of values to list could be more effective!

Comment: I can't reproduce your results at all. As written, your code could not possibly produce output with non-square-bracket characters in the first `print` and empty output in the second. For that matter, on Python 3 (the only currently supported version of Python), you'd end up with `b''` wrapping the output in both cases (because `check_output` produces `bytes` by default). You need to be more specific about which version of Python you're using, what the *exact* output is, and make sure your [MCVE] actually reproduces your problem (which it definitely can't, as posted).

Comment: Side-note: Is the program you're running another Python process that's outputting the stringified form of some `list`? Knowing if that's the case would be useful, because hand-parsing such an output is ugly and error-prone; you'd typically want to use `ast.literal_eval` instead (or have the other process dump the data using the `json` module so you can parse it with the `json` module on your end).